# How to get an authorization token from JuPyter hub using its REST APIs?

Tags: json, rest, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to start a notebook server as described [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/rest-api/index.html#operation--users--name--server-post). I learnt that I need to get an auth token from this and so wanted to get the same, I have to use the api as described [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/rest-api/index.html#path--authorizations-token). It always states "Method not allowed, 405". I am unable to figure out what is the right way to do this.

I tried the following post requests:

```
http://MY_JHUB_ON_K8S_SERVER.com/authorizations/token
```

with the body of `JSON/Application`:

```
{
    "username": "aviral",
    "password": "aviral",
}
```

The headers are:

```
[{"key":"Content-Type","name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":"","type":"text"}]
```

In [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I had tried basic auth as well as no auth. In the basic auth, I pasted the username and password, while when there was no auth, I put the same in the `json body`

I expect to get the token so that I can start a server. Right now, regardless of the permutation and combination, I am getting 405.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be possible using the oath api endpoint but I wasn't successful.
Instead I run this command on the jupyterhub server to generate a token

```
jupyterhub token myusername
```

and then calls should work properly using the rest api:

```
curl --insecure 'https://myjupyterhubserver:8443/hub/api/users' \
-H 'Authorization: Token mygeneratedtoken'
```